# Carousel is not displaying

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, carousel

My carousel is not displaying. I have followed certain principles given by bootstrap but it does not seem to work. Any ideas why?

```
<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <img src="img/background.png">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its better if you can create a fiddle or pen to create a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there you forgot to make the first item active `<div class="carousel-item active">`

Comment: Hi, Thanks it working now. However the slide buttons is not working

Comment: @Mike.U That would be a new question. Do not ask new questions here in the Answer section. Open a new question instead.

Comment: @Mike you forgot this code, and i advice you to check the bootstrap site <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>